# Return an HTTP Request from a Function

Tags: javascript, html, http, return

Good Easter! I am trying to return an HTTP Request from a function, but it's not working how I thought it would. Now, the HTTP request is fine, in which I can show you right here:

```js
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hand';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  alert(eval(Http.responseText)[0]["meanings"][0]["partOfSpeech"])
}
```

As you can see, it alerts it multiple times, which is not what I want. Also, when I do it in a function:

```js
var JSIMS = function() {
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hand';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  return eval(Http.responseText)[0]["meanings"][0]["partOfSpeech"];
}
}
alert(JSIMS())
```

As you can see there, it alerts "undefined". ( In which I purposely made the function return the value and not alert it from **inside** of the function )

Please so me how to fix this with the function returning the value, and **not** alerting it from directly **inside** the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid multiple alert by adding a condition to check if the request status is DONE.

```js
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hand';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  if (Http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    alert(eval(Http.responseText)[0]["meanings"][0]["partOfSpeech"])
  }
}
```

The other option to return your response is to use a callback function to the method to handle the response from the api call as below.

```js
function loadData(callback) {
  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const url='https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hand';
  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
   if (Http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
       callback(eval(Http.responseText)[0].meanings[0].partOfSpeech);
    }
  }
  Http.open("GET", url);
  Http.send();
}

loadData(myCustomFunction);

function myCustomFunction(data) {
  console.log(data); /* Output - Verb */
}
```

Similarly we can use promise to return your data once the api responds

```js
var JISM = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url='https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hand';
    Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
     if (Http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
       resolve(eval(Http.responseText)[0].meanings[0].partOfSpeech);
     }
    }
    Http.onerror = () => reject(Http.statusText);
    Http.open("GET", url);
    Http.send();
  });
}

JISM().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I know that this is returning `data` but where?

Comment: You will receive the data which is retuned from the api inside the callback function - myCustomFunction()

Comment: Can you edit this to show putting all of this in a variable, and then `console.log()` the variable?

Comment: You mean var loadData = function() this way?

Comment: Yes, in that way.

Comment: Check the third snippet

Comment: What does the `then(data => {});` do, because I'm not familiar with that. As you can see in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/WildandRare/zaw2vf5r/1/ , I have a function that scans through an array for functions, but the way you have made your function, returning is not working like the other function above, so can you please show me how to make your function so that it returns it how the other function does in the jsfiddle project. Please tell me if the link doesn't work.

Comment: The .then() function gets executed when the api call in JISM() get a response. It's like giving an instruction, when you get that, do this. Meanwhile why do you want to keep functions as an array. It's not a recommended pattern at all.

Comment: Because that's how it's like in my project, the way I am making my project, there are functions in an array, so if I add that, then it will have to be in an array like everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the received data when ready state is done.
Try this and it works:

```js
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url='https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hand';
Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (Http.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(eval(Http.responseText)[0].meanings[0].partOfSpeech);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't have a function to return the output.

Comment: You talked about multi time alert not returning function and you are welcome.

Comment: Look at the **bottom** of my post/question and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

`xhr.send` should be used after `xhr.onreadystatechange`, but you aren't testing to see `if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)` anyways. In XHR2 you can avoid using a `xhr.onreadystatechange`, and using that condition, if you just do like:

```js
function JSIMS(word){ // I don't like the name of the function... but
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/'+word);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    xhr.onload = function(){
      resolve(this.response[0].meanings[0].partOfSpeech);
    }
    xhr.onerror = ()=>{
      reject(new Error('load error'));
    }
    xhr.send();
  });
}
JSIMS('hand').then(j=>{
  console.log(j);
});
```